# How to start a systemd service when a DVD is inserted?

Tags: linux, udev, systemd

I'm trying to write a simple `systemd` service that gets started when I insert a DVD into my DVD-ROM drive.  However, my service never starts even though I see the relevant `SYSTEMD_WANTS` while running `udevadm monitor --env`.  I can start the service manually and it works as expected.

Here's what I have:

---

#### `/etc/systemd/system/test.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=just touch /tmp/pizza

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/touch /tmp/pizza
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/rm -v /tmp/pizza
```

---

#### `/etc/udev/rules.d/98-dd-one-from-udev.rules`:

```
KERNEL=="sr[0-9]*", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="test.service"
```

---

When I start my service manually with `sudo systemctl start test.service` I see the file `/tmp/pizza` show up, as well as the expected happy things in `journalctl`.

When I monitor the output of `udevadm monitor --env` I see that my `SYSTEMD_WANTS` environment variable *is* being set as expected:

```
...
ID_SERIAL=MATSHITA_UJDA750_DVD_CDRW-0:0
ID_TYPE=cd
ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=MATSHITA
ID_VENDOR_ENC=MATSHITA
ID_VENDOR_ID=05e3
MAJOR=11
MINOR=1
SEQNUM=1822
SUBSYSTEM=block
SYSTEMD_WANTS=test.service  <--- Woohoo!
TAGS=:seat:systemd:uaccess:
USEC_INITIALIZED=6417
```

And yet, my service never starts...

What linkage am I missing here?

For what it's worth, I'm running Arch Linux with `systemd` version 218.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SYSTEMD_WANTS` only handles **"add"/"remove"** events. In case of CD drives, those events are only sent **for the device itself**, *not* for media – so the service will be started when the DVD-ROM drive is detected, and stopped when the drive is unplugged, regardless of what's inside it.

Media changes are reported as "change" events, and systemd doesn't handle those, as it would require understanding specific properties of each device type.

```
udevadm monitor --udev
```

Comment: Dang... Is there any way for me to do this using udev and systemd?

Comment: I guess I can probably listen for `ACTION=="change"` and `RUN+="/usr/sbin/systemctl start test.service"`...  I'll try that out later.

Comment: interested in this myself - in fact I have an additional question: can I start a user service (with "user" level privileges) when a person logs into his account. Kind of like, say a Dropbox like service, that will only start when you log into your account.

Comment: @Sandeep: That doesn't seem even remotely related to my post; please post a new question. (But, you're looking for `~/.config/systemd/user/`.)

Comment: @grawity - actually I am looking for multiple hooks. What you are doing is one of them (for example things like  CD inserted, wifi speed reduced,etc). So, I'm interested in what you come up with. Thanks!